# ng serve not working in Docker container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have this [Docker Compose configuration](https://github.com/Axiol/Docker-Angular-CLI) where I simply create a NodeJS container and install Angular CLI inside.

After a `docker-compose up -d`, I'm able to SSH inside the container with `docker-compose run node bash`. `ng new` works perfectly but `ng serve` does not seem to work. It's launched correctly, no error in the console. But, if I visit `localhost` (ad I mapped port 4200 to 80), nothing loads.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile in your ./.docker/node/ folder?

Comment: Never mind, saw it on github.

Comment: Your link leads to a 404, please update it if you can

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you are missing the [Expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) line such as:

`EXPOSE 4200`

Try placing it before your last RUN command in the docker file.

This line exposes the port in the container itself (4200 in this case) so the mapping from compose works (80:4200).

Compose just does this: forward 80 from the host to 4200 in the container. But it doesn't know or care if the 4200 is actually being listened to. The Expose in the dockerfile makes sure when the image is built, to expose this port for the future running containers, so your ng serve can listen to it.

---

**Resolution**

So to get what you want with `docker-compose run`, use `publish` to publish the ports. As `run` doesn't use the mappings from your `docker-compose.yml`, it ignores them. So use it like this:

`docker-compose run --publish 80:4200 node bash`

Then create the angular app and start it up as you were doing.

---

**Test Example For Future Reference**

`cd tmp` (or any writable folder)

`ng new myProject`

`cd myProject`

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` (--host 0.0.0.0 to listen to all the interfaces from the container)

Then in your browser, go to `localhost` and you should see the angular welcome page now as the port `4200` is published and bound to the host port `80` through the publish command as I showed above.

Everytime you have port forwarding issues, if you open a new terminal keeping the other terminal where you executed the original `run command` and run `docker ps` you will see this in the Ports column:

`0.0.0.0:80->4200/tcp` which means that your host on port 80 is forwarding to your container in port 4200 successfully.

If you see something like `4200/tcp` and not the `->` part, that means there is no mappings or ports published.

Comment: Oh, I did not know you had to manually expose ports, thanks. But still, it does not work. As you can see here, port is exposed https://github.com/Axiol/Docker-Angular-CLI/blob/master/.docker/node/Dockerfile But still does not load

Comment: @Axiol I added an update to my response with all the steps to get what you want!

Comment: I am facing same issue , tried all above it doesnt help me .... (i) i am using EXPOSE correctly just above CMD["ng","serve","-H0.0.0.0"] , (ii) i see 0.0.0.0:80->4200/tcp .... when i go inside container & see process using ps -a i don't see npm running.... very new to npm & docker both , pls help

Comment: @Lav I'll be happy to help if you create a stackoverflow question with your specific case.

Comment: I'm using `docker-compose` and `angular-cli`, and had to use this `command` line for this to work: `command: "npm run -- ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"`. The `--host` part was being parsed by `npm run` rather than `ng serve` without the `--`.

Comment: I think that ``EXPOSE 4200`` is just an indication for others developers using your Dockerfile, it does'nt really do anything https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#expose

Answer (score 52):

Using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` has always worked for me.

The reason this is crucial is that without it, the angular process is only listening on the localhost interface *inside the container* - so even with the docker port mapping, connections from outside the container aren't being received.

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:3000

But if you add the parameter `--host 0.0.0.0` then the angular process will listen on all interfaces, and the docker port mapping will allow connections from outside the container to reach it.

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:3000

So, in summary:

1. you **don't** need the `EXPOSE 4200` line in the Dockerfile
2. you **do** need the port mapping in the docker-compose.yml file
3. you **do** need the CMD line in the Dockerfile, and it should include the host parameter e.g.
   `CMD ["ng","serve","--host", "0.0.0.0"]`
4. you **don't** need to use `docker run`
5. you **can** use `docker-compose up`, which will pick up the port mappings from the docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 49):

try to run [`ng serve`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve#options) with host specified (which is set to 'localhost' by default):

```
ng serve -H 0.0.0.0
```

**UPDATE**
Pay attention, currently (@angular/cli@7) the option is [`--host`](https://angular.io/cli/serve):

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck
```

thanks @antirealm for adding `--disableHostCheck` :)

Comment: It still does not load sadly

Comment: add --disableHostCheck also

Comment: Thanks to both of you --host 0.0.0.0 and --disable-host-check worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

In my `Dockerfile` I was trying the `--disable-host-check` option but the browser would wait indefinitely:

```
CMD ["ng","serve","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]
```

So I added a `hostname: dev.musicng` property in my `docker-compose.yml` file, with its entry in the `/etc/hosts` file: `127.0.1.1 dev.musicng` and then I could see my application appear in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

### Project tree

[image]

### .docker\node\Dockerfile

Install and configure Angular on node based container

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

EXPOSE 4200

USER node

RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.6
```

### docker-compose.yml

- Build the above Dockerfile
- expose port 4200, run the command:

  ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll=2000

> `--host 0.0.0.0` listen to all container interfaces
> `--poll=2000` listen for changes in the folder

```yaml
version: "2.1"

services:
  node:
    container_name: angularcontainer
    build: ./.docker/node/
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    command: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll=2000
```

### Start

Run in project root

```
docker compose up
```

And done!

### Project

https://github.com/wictorChaves/docker-helper/tree/master/projetos/compose/angular

#### Referencias:

- [Docker-Angular-CLI](https://github.com/Axiol/Docker-Angular-CLI)
- [ng serve not detecting file changes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49975130/7986223)

Answer (score 1):

```
ng serve -H 0.0.0.0
```

with 1000 poll property in angular-cli.json (for file change detection)

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {},
    "poll": 1000
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit light on details. Could you explain what this is doing, and why it would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is just installing the angular, you need to have `CMD ["npm start"] or CMD ["ng serve"]` at the end of dockerfile this is the entrypoint for the container which docker executes when you start the container and only then the npm server will start.

`ng serve -H 0.0.0.0 --port <yourportnumber>` will make the ngserve to run on `localhost:<yourportnumber>`there after you can bind the container port number to your local port

Comment: As mentioned, I manually connect to the container to run `ng serve`