# How to access node.js angular application outside container

Tags: node.js, angularjs, docker, docker-container

i have a node js angular application which i am trying to containerize it.

1. i am using Docker file to build the image and run the docker
2. i am not getting any error and the build is success
   [Node.js build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JWLy.png)

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCpj5.png)

Comment: ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4100, open your browser on http://localhost:4100/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.

Comment: Provide your entire `dockerfile` and `docker run` command.

Comment: # Pulling out NODE Image
FROM node:latest

# Creating a main directory to work with Docker
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

# Setup the main dir as working dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the project dir to DOCKER working dir
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Command to install the Angular-Cli@project_version
RUN npm install
RUN npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.2
RUN npm link @angular/cli
RUN ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false
#RUN npm run-script build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ng serve  --port 4100

Comment: please update it in the question can't see it properly in comments.

Comment: added the screen shots for docker file and output of the nodejs build @mchawre

Comment: Why do you think we want *screenshots*?

Comment: @AjayR you are exposing port `8080` and application listening on `4100`, first expose `4100` then `docker run -p 4100:4100 youimage:tag`

Comment: i cannot paste the docker file code hence i posted screen shots. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Why can't you paste it? It's just text.

Comment: @Adiii i did the same no go still i cannot access on my host machine
5c58fecc2d9c        latestops:v2        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:4100->4100/tcp   objective_spence

Answer (score 0):

Since your node.js angular application is running on port 4100. You need expose that port using [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports).

```
docker run -itd -p 4100:4100 myimage:v1
```

***NOTE:*** [-p option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) will expose container port on to the host port.

Now you can access your application at `http://host-ip:4100`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it as well its not working.
root@master:~/ops-automation-services/ops-automation-services# docker run -itd -p 4100:4100 opstest:v1
f1fb7ec1241adbfffc77d276a66798ac76feed7c8135bac969b2485ee8f290d7
root@master:~/ops-automation-services/ops-automation-services# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
                   NAMES
f1fb7ec1241a        opstest:v1          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:4100->4100/tcp, 8080/tcp                 pedantic_kare

Comment: i do not get any error its just do not load anyting

Comment: do this `docker exec -it f1fb7ec1241a sh` it will get you inside the container shell and now run `curl localhost:4100` and `netstat -anp | grep 4100` to check whether your application is up and running and listening on which port.

Comment: i ran the above curl command i get an html out put

# curl localhost:4100
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

i have pasted half  of it . when i to a netstat -anp | grep 4100 i get netstat not found

Comment: What happens when you do `curl localhost:4100` or `curl host-ip:4100` from the host machine. Can you paste the output here.

Comment: stills same issue , logged into container and did curl localhost:4100 i get an out put html format . i did a net stat -anp | grep 4100

root@5c58fecc2d9c:/usr/src/app# netstat -anp | grep 4100
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7/ng serve --port 4

Comment: Are you trying to curl from your host machine.

Comment: No mchware i have a ec2 instance which is ubuntu i have docker on it . i am exposing 4100 port from docker and i am hitting my ec2 ip:4100 @mchawre

Comment: Have you verified port 4100 of your ubuntu ec2 machine is open in security group.

Comment: Also if on linux shell of ubuntu ec2 machine the curl command works?

Comment: the curl command and netstat works only with in docker container. when i use docker exec -it <container id> and then curl, netstat.

i installed net-tools on host ec2 instance and did  netstat -anp | grep 4100 i get the below output
root@ip-172-31-83-86:~# netstat -anp | grep 4100
tcp6       0      0 :::4100                 :::*                    LISTEN      4690/docker-proxy
@mchawre

Comment: what happens when you do curl from the ec2 shell?

Comment: root@ip-172-31-83-86:~# curl localhost:4100
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: try to curl with private/public ip of machine

Comment: when i try public ip:4100 it going to next prompt and dose not do anything. 
private ip :4100 its says connection refused. @mchawre

Comment: go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778868/ng-serve-not-working-in-docker-container something might help.

Comment: finally i got it resolved but my concern is if we use --host 0.0.0.0 in Docker file . it give me a vulnerability .root@master:~/ops-automation-services/ops-automation-services# docker run -p 8080:4200 opslatest:v1
WARNING: server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck"

Comment: i resolved it by following that link which you gave me. but will it cause a security issue