# Containerizing Angular project with Docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I've recently learned how to use Docker and am trying to containerize an Angular project that I've been working on.

The project's `package.json` is as following:

```
{
"name": "argon-dashboard-angular",
"version": "1.0.1",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --port 8080",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/common": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/core": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/forms": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/http": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/router": "7.2.4",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.1",
  "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
  "chart.js": "2.7.3",
  "clipboard": "2.0.4",
  "core-js": "2.6.4",
  "ngx-clipboard": "11.1.9",
  "ngx-toastr": "9.1.2",
  "nouislider": "13.1.1",
  "rxjs": "6.4.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.1",
  "@angular/cli": "7.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.4",
  "@angular/language-service": "7.2.4",
  "@types/jasmine": "3.3.8",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
  "@types/node": "11.9.0",
  "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
  "jasmine-core": "3.3.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
  "karma": "4.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
  "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
  "protractor": "5.4.2",
  "ts-node": "8.0.2",
  "tslint": "5.12.1",
  "typescript": "3.2.4"
  }
}
```

My `Dockerfile` is as following:

```
FROM node:10.18.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","start"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I build from the image and run my container:

```
docker build .
docker run <container-id>
```

Once the container is running, I tried to access http://localhost:8080 , but the browser reads "localhost refused to connect".

Also, my Docker Desktop app shows these buttons next to my container:

[image: Docker container missing button]

Usually there would be another button to the left that opens the container in my browser at its port.

Also, after looking through some tutorials, I noticed that many suggested using an Nginx Docker image to serve my web app. Is this necessary? Why can't I serve my app through `ng serve` ?

Comment: The dev server isn't designed for production use. You're better off with a multi-stage build where the Node container runs ng build and the result is served by e.g. Nginx. This will also result in a substantially smaller container (the Nginx image is much lighter than any Node, and you won't need node_modules etc.).

Comment: Try to move `EXPOSE 8080` this line above in the dockerfile and then try to `docker restart <containerId>`

Comment: Change last line as CMD ["ng","serve","--host", "0.0.0.0"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng serve not working in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778868/ng-serve-not-working-in-docker-container)

Comment: Did you map port while running the Docker container?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
option --publish-all , -P

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. So will the Nginx image be used only for production, or can I use it for my dev environment as well?

Comment: Just for prod. If you want to do dev in a container you'd set it up completely differently, e.g. mounting directories into it rather than copying files.

Comment: @DupinderSingh I tried both suggestions, did not change anything.

Comment: @AndrzejSydor calling  `docker run --publish-all -P <container-id>`  did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe one more question, so would it make sense to maintain two Dockerfiles: one for dev, another for prod? Looking at this page  https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/  it sounds like having two Dockerfiles isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

For building purpose it's better to use Multistage building like below:

```
FROM node:10 AS builder

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN ng new my-app --routing=true --style=css --skipGit=true --minimal=true
WORKDIR /app/my-app
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /app/my-app/dist/my-app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: What if I'm just trying to build a dev server? Should I still be using the Nginx image?