# How to host angular application in Docker?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, devops

I am looking for a solution for correct docker file but when I write localhost:8080 on browser I can see nginx but I can not see default angular website on the browser. What can I do with my Docker file. What it is wrong ?

```
FROM node:12.8-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Step 2: Use build output from 'builder'
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
LABEL version="1.0"

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=builder . /app

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

[image]

Comment: In addition to a correct Dockerfile, you need to properly run the container. If you want to access your service on `localhost:8080` from a browser running on your machine, you will need to [publish that port](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports), which is something that happens at runtime. That's not something that gets baked into your Dockerfile.

Comment: Your final `COPY` line is copying to `/app` in the Nginx image, not the `WORKDIR` you set in the line previous.  Did you mean to have the arguments in the opposite order, `COPY --from=builder /app .`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right off the bat I see a couple things, like `EXPOSE`

> First, in your Docker config you are missing the
> [Expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)
> option/line such as:

`EXPOSE 4200`

Insert it before your last RUN command in the docker file, to allow the port in the container (for e.g. `port 4200`) so the mapping from compose works (80:4200)

Its forwarding port 80 to 4200, [essentially mapping your angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779529/6085193).

---

2. Update your config file: A good ref [sample of sanitized](https://medium.com/better-programming/7-steps-to-dockerize-your-angular-9-app-with-nginx-915f0f5acac) docker config. You should compare your image with this to update your install with yarn, and copy to the correct output dir. etc.

---

```
FROM node:13.3.0 AS compile-image
// install
RUN npm install -g yarn

WORKDIR /opt/ng
COPY .npmrc package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH" 

# configure your expose port
#expose the port
   EXPOSE 4200
COPY . ./
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/ng/dist/app-name /usr/share/nginx/html
```

---

3. You may need to forward the port from the container to your system / host :

   `docker run -p 4200:4200 test:latest`