# ng serve not working in Docker container but express.js does

Tags: angular, docker, wsl-2

I've read similar question [ng serve not working in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778868/ng-serve-not-working-in-docker-container) but I don't understand why do I have to specify a host `0.0.0.0` to run `ng serve`. For comparison, I ran a simple script with express.js in the same container on the same port and in this case the website was served at localhost:8080 **without defining 0.0.0.0 host**.

As I understand both servers (`ng serve` and `express.js`) are working the same way. Both runs inside container but only express can be accessed in browser and I'm confused why `ng serve` isn't.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run LTS Node.js container with name `angular-test` from CLI and publish port 8080:4200
   `docker container run --name angular-test -it -v ${PWD}:/app/ -p 8080:4200 node:lts /bin/bash`
2. connect to container's terminal `docker container attach angular-test`
3. go to angular project and run `ng serve`
4. go to browser `localhost:8080` but returns "The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. ...`
5. stop `ng serve`
6. run `node test-express` to start express.js server on the same port `4200`
7. go to browser `localhost:8080` and website is loaded without any issue, text `Express.js works!` is visible

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4200

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Express.js works!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

It probably doesn't matter but I'm using Docker for Windows with WSL2 (Windows 10 Pro).

Comment: Maybe this should answer to your query I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52425925/8692369

Comment: No, I have seen this thread but it does not answer my question. Why do I have to specify `-h 0.0.0.0` for `ng serve` while for express.js that's not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express.js utilizes the NodeJs`s method
`server.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])` [see documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback)

> If host is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.

If host isn't specified, Node.js sets unspecified IP address `::` or `0.0.0.0` as default. If you want to know what host is being defaulted, call `server.address()` inside `app.listen()` where `server` is an object returned by [http.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) which extends [net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server).

```js
const port = 4200;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('App listening at', server.address())
})
```

`server.address()` should return an object, which in my case is

```js
{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 4200 }
```

It is now clear that express.js is listening on `::`, not `localhost` as I expected.